# Can't get my python pyramid to show up correctly

Tags: python

Here's the code I've been working with

```
def pyramid(n):
    print('Pyramid Output')
    if (n%2 != 0 and n > 0):
        for i in range(1,n-1,1):
                    spaces = int(.5*n - i + .5)
                    sides = (i-1)
                    print(spaces*' ' + sides*"-" + '-' +sides*"-")
```

But past a certain value, the pyramid becomes left justified and starts adding values to the right side. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `spaces` computation (and also your `range`) is wrong. To build a 5 tiles high pyramid you need to add 4,3,2,1,0 spaces in front:

```
4444-
333---
22-----
1-------
---------
```

For bigger `n` your `spaces` computation is simply wrong. Lets take  `n=51`:

```
# on row 20: 
spaces = int(0.5*51 - 20 + .5)  # => 25.5 -20 + 0.5 = 6 ... still 31 rows to go

# on row 26: 
spaces = int(0.5*51 - 26 + .5)  # => 25.5 -26 + 0.5 = 0 ... still 21 rows to go

# on row 30: 
spaces = int(0.5*51 - 30 + .5)  # => 25.5 -30 + 0.5 is negative ... how add negative space?
```

Fix:

```
def pyramid(n):
    print('Pyramid Output')
    if (n%2 != 0 and n > 0):  # no even row numbers pyramids allowed!
        for i in range(1,n+1,1): # for n=5 yours is 1,2,3 - probably shold be range(1,n+1)
            spaces = n-i 
            sides = 2*(i-1)+1 # optimized
            print(spaces*' ', sides*'-', sep="") # optimized                    

pyramid(51)
```